# how to use IViewActionDelegate?

Tags: eclipse, events, interface

i have added a menu item to the variablesview menu by extending the org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus
extension point and what im trying to do is that when someone right clicks a variable and clicks my menu item i would parse the variable's value to an Ip format.

i succeded in adding the menu item and responding to a click with the IViewActionDelegate interface, but when someone clicks on my menu item the information given by IAction event is'nt helping with knowing  which Object occoured the event or what is the value of the variable.

my question is, if there is a way to locate the variable's value after clicking my menu item?
or is there another way of using the interface IViewActionDelegate that i dont know of, or i dont use it correctly?.

i have checked a lot in google about how to add a menu item and found good guide:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html

but it does'nt solve my problem, i really need help on this subject.

thanks.